# executing subcommand with supervisord

Tags: linux, supervisord

I want to run my server with ip address as an argument.

```
./server-no-ssl 80 "$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)"
```

i am using supervisor with config

```
[program:allsparkrt]
command=/home/ubuntu/server-no-ssl 80 "$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)"
directory=/home/ubuntu/
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
stderr_logfile=/var/log/allspark_server.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/allspark_server.out.log
stopsignal=INT
stopwaitsecs=60
```

the curl command is taken as argument instead of ip adress from curl.
Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supervisord doesn't execute shell for specified command, so curl isn't treated as command, but only as a string. Check this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/722542) for more details. As a workaround you may try using `bash -c "desired command"` construction.